# Overriding td style over tr in Dash dbc.Table

Tags: html, css, plotly-dash

I've defined a `dbc.Table`:

```py
table = dbc.Table(
    [html.Thead(html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in h_table.columns]))] +
    [html.Tbody(rows)]
)
```

And a css:

```css
.cell-pass {
  background-color: #36ae7c;
  color: white;
}
    
.cell-fail {
  background-color: #eb5353;
  color: white;
}
    
tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
   background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
    
tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: white;
}
```

In the code I set `className` to either 'cell-fail' or 'cell-pass' for some cells (not all!).

However the `tbody tr:nth-of-type` seems to override the `td` style so it does not get applied. If I decide to not use `dbc.Table` and `Thead`/`Tbody` it works fine though, but I don't want to do that :-)

Can someone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 0):

class names `.cell-pass` or `.cell-fail` have a lower specificity compared to the `tbody tr:nth-of-type` selector, which targets all tr elements within the tbody.

You may increase the specificity of those selectors by narrowing to td only:

```
td.cell-pass {
  background-color: #36ae7c;
  color: white;
}

td.cell-fail {
  background-color: #eb5353;
  color: white;
}
```

Last way which I do not suggest is to use `!important` for `background-color`. That will be the last solution if you have any other limitations to narrow down the class names.